pm2 npm command not found in code deploy windows ec2 machine
I'm currently working on deploying a Node.js application on a Windows EC2 instance using CodeDeploy. I've added the user data script in the Autoscaling Group to install Node.js and the required package before the CodeDeploy hooks can run the PM2 start command to start the Node.js application.
However, when I checked the CodeDeploy logs for the before install script, it showed the error "term 'pm2' is not recognized"

When I logged into the EC2 instance using admin credentials and ran the before install script manually, it worked without any issues.
I've also tried different suggestions, such as using the full  PM2 path  to run the command and adding the path to user and system environment variables.

Additionally, I attempted to install PM2 globally using "npm install pm2 -g" from user data scripts at Windows startup, but none of these approaches were successful.
Since the Autoscaling Group shut down the EC2 machine at night and starts a new EC2 machine in the morning, I've written automation scripts to install Node.js and PM2 at the startup level.
Edit: I also tried to install the pm2 from code deploy before script on exception. Unfortunately, this approach also failed as pm2 is not available in other life cycle hook.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in the script. I would greatly appreciate any help in providing a solution.
Thank you.
